# Which STL container for ordered data with key-based access?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Let's say I have a collection of Person objects, each of which looks like this:

```
class Person 
{
  string Name;
  string UniqueID;
}
```

Now, the objects must be stored in a container which allows me to order them so that I can given item X easily locate item X+1 and X-1.

However, I also need fast access based on the UniqueID, as the collection will be large and a linear search won't cut it.

My current 'solution' is to use a std::list in conjunction with a std::map. The list holds the Persons (for ordered access) and the map is used to map UniqueID to a reference to the list item. Updating the 'container' typically involves updating both map and list.

It works, but I feel there should be a smarter way of doing it, maybe `boost:bimap`.  Suggestions?

**EDIT:** There's some confusion about my requirement for "ordering". To explain, the objects are streamed in sequentially from a file, and the 'order' of items in the container should match the file order. The order is unrelated to the IDs.

Comment: What do you mean by `X+1` and `X-1` ? I have a feeling it does not refer to the `UniqueID` field, so what is it ? What order are your referring to ?

Comment: I'm referring to the ordering within the container. i.e (assuming a vector) Array[X], [X-1] and [X+1]

Comment: What is the order in the container?  I think that's what Matthieu is trying to pin down.

Comment: @Joel, The order in the container is just "the order in the container." There's no field that specifies it (yet). It's just the order in which the items are streamed in from a file. (and yes, it's important)

Comment: In that case, a bimap is probably the way to go.

Comment: I am under the impression that I'm fed information piece meal. It's quite frustrating. From your description, there is no insertion at a random point in the list, yet you told Neil that you need delete and insert at any point without iterator invalidation... would you care to clarify ?

Comment: @Matthieu, Sorry to frustrate you - not my intention. I'd mistakenly assumed random insertion/deletion was an obvious requirement that I didn't need to state. As for iterator invalidation, that's not a specific requirement: It's just that my current solution approach (list + map) means insert/delete is "trivial" (only a single map entry needs to be added/deleted). With Neil's suggestion (vector/deque + map), the ENTIRE map would need rebuilding after every insert/delete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`boost:bimap` is the most obvious choice. `bimap` is based on `boost::multi_index`, but `bimap` has simplified syntax. Personally I will prefer `boost::multi_index` over `boost::bimap` because it will allow to easily add more indices to the `Person` structure in the future.

Comment: By the way, question to native speakers: `indices` or `indexes`?

Comment: `Indices` is the technically correct plural noun. But everone would understand `indexes`...

Comment: Thanks. frustratingly I;ve found that my toolchain (C++Builder 2010) doesn't support boost::multi_index or bimap, but hey, at least I know what I *should* be using.

Answer (score 7):

There is no Standard Library container that does what you want - so you will have to use two containers or the Boost solution. If using two containers, I would normally prefer a vector or a deque over a list, in almost all circumstances.

Comment: @Neil, Thanks. Using a vector would mean that deleting or inserting an item would potentially invalidate ALL the references in my map. Hence the list.

Comment: @Roddy: I am unsure of your requirements, but I have an idea that you use your list as a queue. If I am wrong, then please feel free to correct me, but if I am right, then Neil's `deque` solution makes sense.

Comment: @Matthieu, Sadly not: I still need random insert/delete that won't invalidate locations of all other items.

Comment: How can you need insertion if the elements are read from a file in a specific order ? It seems to me you would never need anything else than deletion, since records can't magically appear in the file.

Comment: @Matthieu: Think of it like a text editor: Open a ordered file of 'lines', user then adds/deletes/edits at random, and we finally save out an updated ordered file of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use two maps , one having Person as Key and another one having UniqueId as Key, but that requires updating both of them.

you can create a callback function which updates both the maps whenever there is any change.

Comment: "you can create a callback function..." Ah - how do I do that??